# python: Unable to confgure handler file [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to launch a serve and a web application running. But I let this error:

```
C:\repositories\ABC\branches\user1\web_layer\service_layer>python mana
ge.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 20, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\log.py", line 87, in configur
e_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "C:\python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 803, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "C:\python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 585, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 2] No such file or direct
ory: 'C:\\logs\\enforce_web.log'

C:\repositories\ABC\branches\user1\web_layer\service_layer>cd ../
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does the file C:\\logs\\enforce_web.log exists?

Comment: I don't see it on C:/

Answer (score 0):

This is a system specific error."C:\logs\enforce_web.log" has been hard coded. You can probably find this line in base.py of your project.Edit it out there. Make it `filename': 'logger.log',`